# how to cancel to call the function in python tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a reminder application in python using the Tkinter module. I need to cancel to call the function when the user clicks on the cancel remind button. I tried to assign the time (time variable that contains the time in milliseconds when the function will call) variable to 0, but it does not work.
sorry,for late respond i was creating small example this is the smallest example i can create.
code:

```
# example:

from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, TOP
from tkinter.ttk import Button
time=10000

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
def function_to_cancel():
    global time
    time=0 # not works

button = Button(root, text = 'Remind Me! after 10 seconds')
button.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)
cancel=Button(root,text='Cancel Remind',command=function_to_cancel)#this button will cancel the remind
cancel.pack()
print('Running...')
root.after(time, root.destroy)
mainloop()
```

If you understand the question, please answer.

Comment: The reason Stackoverflow doesn't allow you to paste the code here is because it's too long. Please make a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: please answer ):

Comment: Please create an example in which we can see the issue you are facing, we seriously dont want to debug 261 lines of code

Comment: okay creating a example

Comment: created a  example

Comment: please answer ):

Comment: i am deleting this question no one is answering me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the task ID returned by `.after()` and then use the ID with `.after_cancel()` to cancel the scheduled task:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, TOP
from tkinter.ttk import Button
time=10000

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
def function_to_cancel():
    #global time
    #time=0 # not works
    root.after_cancel(after_id)

button = Button(root, text = 'Remind Me! after 10 seconds')
button.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)
cancel=Button(root,text='Cancel',command=function_to_cancel)#this button will cancel the remind
cancel.pack()
print('Running...')
# save the ID returned by after()
after_id = root.after(time, root.destroy)
mainloop()
```